# Eager Loading Multiple Relationships

Tags: laravel, nested, one-to-many, relation

i have these below  relation with model.

---

```
  class order
  {
  public function finances()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Finance::class,'finance_id');
  }
  }
  class Finance
  {
   public function prices()
   {
      return $this->hasMany(Price::class, 'finance_id');
   }
public function latestPrice()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Price::class,'finance_id')->latest();
}

public function orders()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Order::class, 'finance_id');
}
```

}

when i execute this query

```
$orders = Order::with(['finances.prices.latestPrice'])->get();
```

i got this error.Call to undefined relationship [latestPrice] on model [App\Price].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to respect the syntax of laravel, check the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) :

```
$orders = Order::with(['finances.prices', 'finances.latestPrice'])->get();
```

Comment: This is not correct, the `Order` class does not have `prices` and `latestPrice` relationships, only the `Finance` class does.